# How to find a control defined in the style of another control UWP 8.1

Tags: c#, uwp

So here's the deal,
I have a `GridView` which uses a `style` that has a definition of pretty much everything you see in that `GridView` and is defined in a different file.

This makes it hard to reach the controls within that `Style`.
problem is I can't change it so the `GridView` will have the definitions in it cause it's a standard in the program.

So what I'm looking for is a way to access a button defined in that `GridView`'s `Style`.

this is the definition of this style (roughly):

```
<Style x:Key="GlobalUserHeader" TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                    <Grid Background="#FF262524" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        ...
                        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="0">
                            ...
                            <Button x:Name="AuthUserStyleButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource AuthUserStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0">
                                <Button.Flyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding StoreId, Converter={StaticResource TranslateConverter}, ConverterParameter='T_A_Common_SignOut'}" Command="{Binding SignOutCommand}"/>
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </Button.Flyout>
                            </Button>
                            ...
                        </Grid>
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

here's the `GridView` definition:

```
<GridView x:Name="GlobalUserHeaderGridView" Style="{StaticResource GlobalUserHeader}"/>
```

I managed to get to the `ControlTemplate` level in my code but that was it.
it's in namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find a control defined in the style of another control UWP 8.1

Control has [`GetTemplateChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.gettemplatechild) method that could use to retrieves the named element in the instantiated `ControlTemplate` visual tree. But it is protected method. So we need to re-package this method as public method.

```
public sealed class MyGridView : GridView
{
    public MyGridView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(GridView);
    }

    public DependencyObject GetChildWithName(string childName)
    {
        return GetTemplateChild(childName);
    }
}


<Page
    ......
    xmlns:local="using:InkCanvas"
    ......

<local:MyGridView x:Name="GlobalUserHeaderGridView" Style="{StaticResource GlobalUserHeader}"/>
```

**Usage**

```
var btn = GlobalUserHeaderGridView.GetChildWithName("AuthUserStyleButton")
```

Comment: I've created the class but the xaml won't recognize it.

Comment: have you added  namesapce for  `MyGridView` like this  `local:MyGridView`?

Comment: where do i add it?

Comment: Doesn't work. You see this button isn't this GridView's child so your method returns. It's the Style's child, but Style is a sealed class so i can't use your suggestion

Comment: I tested and it work well, have you implement above in your side?

Comment: I did, returns null... I'll try again though, maybe I've missed something

Comment: have you used the your custom style for your GridView?

Comment: yes and i used your code, both c# and xaml and yet i get null as a result.

Comment: could you share a mini sample for us, I will edit base on your demo.

Comment: I'm not sure what more i could share that i haven't yet did. the style is defines in file a. the gridview is defined in file b. the c# code trying to get the child is in file c. i don't know what you did different but the code for that is in my original question.

Comment: I place code [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ScaleTest), may be you could check.

Comment: seems pretty much the same unless listview and gridview have a difference when it comes to finding children. Anyway I ran a scan to find how many children the GridView has and it returns 0. which means as i suspoected that the button is the Style's child. I have no idea how you managed to get something with your code the way it's written.

Comment: Could you share your code sample, I will test base on your demo.